# Word for the view of sun hitting a surface on a neighboring building or natural feature

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I really appreciate the warm glowing light you can see when you look out other buildings or surfaces from a terrace or a window.  This effect is especially pleasant late in the day as the sun gets low on the horizon.

'Indirect lighting' is what the effect is inside and around me, but that does not capture this particular sort of view quality. Perhaps there is an architectural term for it ?

"Lots of light" or "indirect light" can be achieved many ways: a reflecting surface isn't always required ... the sky and clouds etc let some light in, even on a shady side of a building. That idea of needing less lamps on not what I'm talking about.

An answer can either be a word or a short term (perhaps an adjective coupled with the word 'view'?).

Sample sentence:

Great space with a radiant light reflected in from neighboring building.

Great space with _____

Answer (score 1):

***Gleam*** or ***gleaming*** (view) would fit.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).